# Fetch mysql data from PHP using radiobutton control

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to manipulate PHP code to search for specfic data in the sql database that matched.

For example, let's say I want to search for an IP matched by a username in the sql database, they're all in the same rows, I select 'IP' in the radiobutton, input the username in the text field - My PHP code searches all for what's in the user database, finds the usernames, outputs only the ip address ( not anything else ), in the row titled 'IP Address' for that specific input. How would I go about doing this?

I want the radiobuttons to be a case, so if I select IP, it'll search IP matched by username, if I select UID, it'll search for UID matched by username and output it, and etc, etc.

**HTML:**

```
    <form action="" method = "POST">
  <input type="radio" name="someName" value="ip"> IP<br>
  <input type="radio" name="someName" value="username"> Username<br>
  <input type="radio" name="someName" value="uid"> UID
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_hostname.';dbname='.$db_database.';charset=utf8mb4', $db_termname,$db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        if(array_key_exists('term',$_REQUEST)){
            $stm=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
            $stm->execute(array($_REQUEST['term']));
            while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo $row['ip'];  
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: you select ip in radio button, username in textfield and submit the form. now you wanted the ip address of the username stored in `IP ADDRESS` column of database?

Comment: @Sanzeeb Aryal If I select IP in radio button, where-by the username's IP is in the database next to the username in the columns UID, IP, USERNAME, I submit the form whatever matches the username it then should output the IP address, and if I select UID it will give me UID of username in database. Using the case in PHP working with the radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should be like:

```
 <form action="" method = "POST">
      <input type="radio" name="someName" value="ip"> IP<br>
      <input type="radio" name="someName" value="uid"> UID<br>
      Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name" > <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"> Submit<br>
    </form>
```

and your php file :

```
    <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            $submit=isset($_POST['submit']);
            if($submit)  
{
              $name=$_POST['somename'];
              $username=$_POST['username'];
              $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_hostname.';dbname='.$db_database.';charset=utf8mb4', $db_termname,$db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
              $stm=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
              $stm->bind_param("s",$username);
              $stmt->execute();
              $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              if($name=='ip')
        {                       echo $row['ip'];  
        }
               else if($name=='uid')  
          {
                    echo $row['uid];
           }
 }
```

Comment: Thank-you so much <3